# How can I make a cycles material like white cotton material for a doctors coat?

Tags: materials

[image][image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqp32.png)[[image]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwANQ.jpg)[[image]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUc00.png)I am very new to blender and am currently on a very steep learning curve. I am trying to make a nice white coat material. I have managed to make nice materials in other colours. But whenever I use a white colour they tend to come out grey. Above is my current node set up (from a youtube tutorial).

Could somebody help me out with this?

Thanks!

Comment: For questions like this please provide information on what  you have tried and show your current material nodes and an image showing what you aspire to get. Please use the [edit] link to add additional information to your question

Comment: Hi I have included my node set up, i'll attach a photo of what i would like now.

Comment: It can be usefull if you show a picture of your actual render too, shaders are just how a meterial react to light, so if your light isn't good, your material will not looks good neither.

Comment: Andrew shows making a detailed cloth material in his recent [flag tutorial](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-animated-flag/), jump to about 35 mins to see the material.

Answer (score 3):

The velvet shader often results in darker colors, so for creating a cotton material I would stay away from that. Here is a node setup for a simple cotton fabric:

[image: Main Nodes]

Utilizing this very nice cloth texture method:

[image: Cloth texture]
[From this thread](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?278285-Yet-Another-Thread-about-Cycles-Materials&p=2343097&viewfull=1#post2343097)

**Final result:**

[image: Final]

Comment: Great I have done that and the I really like the material, I think my issue may be lighting. An issue I am struggling to get my head around. For this design I need these lapels to be lit up really nicely, but as you can see they don't. I'll attach my set up as well as what I am getting at the top.

Comment: @Md If you are struggling with lighting, I highly recommend that you read the definitive article, [Lighting tips from the masters](https://bensimonds.com/2010/06/03/lighting-tips-from-the-masters/) by Ben Simonds. Also, you should check out Andrew Price's tutorial on the subject: [Mastering Lighting](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/mastering-lighting/).